# How do you stub out calls to get properties?

Tags: mocking, stub, fakeiteasy

Consider the following interface...

```
public interface MyInterface
{
    bool MyProperty { get; }
}
```

I am attempting to stub out a call to the `get` function of this property in [fakeiteasy](http://code.google.com/p/fakeiteasy/).

```
[Test]
public void Foo()
{
    var fake = A.Fake<MyInterface>();
    var sut = new MySUT(fake);
    A.CallTo(() => fake.MyProperty).Returns(true);

    var result = sut.Foo();

    Assert.IsTrue(result);
}
```

The system-under-test's Foo() method simply returns the value of the MyProperty get property call. Unfortunately, this test always fails. When debugging, it seems the `get` property is always returning false.

How can I stub out the return value of a `get` property call?

**EDIT** - Adding MySUT class's code (as requested in comments)

```
public class MySUT
{
    private readonly MyInterface _myInterface;

    public MySUT(MyInterface myInterface)
    {
        _myInterface = myInterface;
    }

    public bool Foo()
    {
        return _myInterface.MyProperty;
    }
}
```

Comment: How is your concrete MySUT constructor and MySut.Foo() implemented?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I changed

```
var sut = MySUT(fake);
```

to

```
var sut = new MySUT(fake);
```

and then it worked in my test solution.

I used FakeItEasy 1.7.4257.42 and NUnit for the test. The main project and test project was separated in 2 different assemblies.

Comment: The lack of `new` was actually just a typo when I was writting up the question for SO, my real code wasn't missing it. My real code was a bit more complicated so I didn't bother including it. Looking for the `new` keyword actually made me realize my other "not relavant" code was the problem. I had stubbed out a few more methods on `MyInterface` which were being executed in the constructor of `MySUT`. I stubbed these calls out *AFTER* the call to `new MySUT()` when they needed to be setup before the constructor call. Serves me right for trying to simplify.